# Read file content from a form upload file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use the following code to read the get files from the file system
The code is from a blog post called [Building a File Uploader with NodeJs](https://coligo.io/building-ajax-file-uploader-with-node/).

I was able to see the UI, etc when I ran my project.

I cannot use the following code since I don't have an `uploads` folder in my project (`form.uploadDir`)

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){

    // create an incoming form object
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    // specify that we want to allow the user to upload multiple files in a single request
    form.multiples = true;

    // store all uploads in the /uploads directory - cannot use it
    //form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads');

    // every time a file has been uploaded successfully,
    // rename it to it's original name
    form.on('file', function(field, file) {
        fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name));
    });

    // log any errors that occur
    form.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('An error has occurred: \n' + err);
    });

    // once all the files have been uploaded, send a response to the client
    form.on('end', function() {
        res.end('success');
    });
    // parse the incoming request containing the form data
    form.parse(req);

});
```

> My question is how should I get the file from the UI with the code
>   above? I need to get the file content from the form when I choose my file.

The application is `deployed` to the cloud and when I use `localhost`, I use the following code (which works)

```
const readStream = fs.createReadStream("./file.html");
```

...

```
const writeStream = sftp.createWriteStream("/index.html");
```

...

```
readStream.pipe(writeStream);
```

Which creates a file from the file system with the correct path and overwrites it with another file (like here `index.html`).

Comment: Isn't the file the second argument in the callback for `form.on('file'...`

Comment: @adeneo - this is what I thought but the E2E is not working ...(I deploy the app to the cloud so it's very difficult to debug it...) there is some simple way which I can print the file (from `form.on('file'...`) that was uploaded to the console (logs is working...) that I will able to see the file content which I choose in the form was read in the cloud ...therefore its a bit tricky ...

Comment: There is no cloud, it's just a bunch of someone elses computers connected together. For logging the file, `console.log(file)` inside the event handler comes to mind?

Comment: @adeneo - I use your suggestion like: `console.log("the file is-> " + file);` and I got in the console `OUT the file is-> [object Object]` , if I should write it I should use like `readStream.pipe(file);` ? Please write it as answer and I'll close the question . Thanks!

Comment: @adeneo - Please add your suggestion as answer so I can close this question and resolved. thanks

Comment: I don't know what you did to resolve this? Post your own answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As @aedneo said, when the user choose file the file is created in the upload folder , I just needed to rename it and give the right path to the write stream method and it works!